# is there a function for partial sum?

Tags: r

I want to do something like

```
foo = c(1, 1, 1)
bar = magic_function(foo, sum, init=0)
```

where `bar` is `1 2 3`, i.e. the partial sum of `foo`. Is there such a function, or what is the best way of doing it (avoiding a for-loop)?

Comment: Did you try `cumsum`? What is the `init = 0` argument supposed to do?

Comment: you should have put that as an answer. Cheers. The `init=0` is just the initial value. I'm used to use the C++ function `accumulate`

Comment: `cumsum` is the optimal solution, but `magic_function` looks like how `Reduce` works with `accumulate=TRUE`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Combining James's comment and mine into a formal answer, here are a few options:

```
> foo = c(1, 1, 1)
> cumsum(foo)
[1] 1 2 3
> Reduce("+", foo, accumulate = TRUE)
[1] 1 2 3
> Reduce("sum", foo, accumulate = TRUE)
[1] 1 2 3
```